# STL std::stack C++

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I need a C++ program a stack (I'm gonna to use `std::stack`) but what is the stack doing if it is full and I want to push another element? Does it use FIFO to delete the oldest (first) element of the stack? That's what I need.

Comment: `std::stack`, if using the default `std::deque` container, doesn't have a hard limit on its size. If it can't allocate, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Logically, stacks are never full. If you push a new element, it just gets added to the top. Nothing gets deleted. If you need to remove the first element use `std::queue` or `std::deque`.

Comment: A stack can't possibly have a FIFO algorithm. A stack is a LIFO structure - only the top of the stack can normally be added/removed. FIFO is possible using `std::deque` (a double-ended queue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) has no size limit. By default, it is a wrapper around `std::deque`, which will grow as necessary to hold as many elements as you wish until no more memory can be allocated. At that point a `push()` will result in an [out of memory exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc). `std::list` and `std::vector` may also be used as the underlying container, and will behave in the same way.

If you want to get crazy, you can implement your own fixed-size container and implement whatever behavior you wish.

Comment: For a fixed size stack a circular buffer would be a good choice.  Too bad there's none in the standard library.